# Android drawable item animation - React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, react-native, android-drawable

I am making android splash screen in my app, i am using React Native, but making splash screen in android drawable component. I am not familiar with android and i want to make my image on splash screen to bounce up and down. But i dont know how to do it. This is my splash screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <item
        android:width="180dp"
        android:height="90dp"
        android:drawable="@mipmap/icon"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

This is my SplashActivity:
package com.nasapecenjara;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Thank u everybody that can help.

Answer (score 0):

At first, you have to create an activity. Where the SplashScreen will appear. Then you have to create a XML file for the bounce animation. Like this, 
**bounce.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator">

    <scale
          android:duration="2000"
          android:fromXScale="1.0"
          android:fromYScale="0.0"
          android:toXScale="1.0"
          android:toYScale="1.0" />
</set>
```

Then use this above xml into the SplashScreen Activity

```
Animation an2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.bounce);
your_logo.startAnimation(an2);
```

After finishing the animation, go to the main activity. And finish the current SplashScreen Activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer. I am not good with anroid, can u review my Splash activity and tell me where to put those code u provided. I added Splash Activity code into my question.